# Template spacebar seems to be empty, although helper gives a result

Tags: javascript, meteor

This is my collection 'articles':

```
{ 
    "_id" : "ataRpHNmzznphBLCY", 
    "title" : "Article" }
{
    "_id" : "Mp7GooaRdYzekRq8R",
    "title" : "Category 1",
    "parent" : "ataRpHNmzznphBLCY"
}
{
    "_id" : "ieGRjyYQZ8xAQMX9i",
    "title" : "Category 2",
    "parent" : "ataRpHNmzznphBLCY"
}
```

**template**

```
<template name="editor">
    {{#each section}}
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><input class="newElement" data-section="{{_id}}" type="text"></li>
        </ul>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

**helper**

```
Template.editor.helpers({
    section: function(){
        var articleId = Session.get('articleId'); // = 'ataRpHNmzznphBLCY'
        return Articles.find({ parent: articleId });
    }
});
```

But I don't get an output. It seems `section` is empty. But I can't see why as if I'm doing `db.articles.find({ parent: 'ataRpHNmzznphBLCY' }).pretty()` I get two results.

Comment: According to the shape of your last piece of code you are executing it in the `meteor mongo` shell. Your helpers are executed on the client. I am fairly certain that it is thus a pub/sub issue. Try to `meteor add autopublish` and see if it solves your issue. If it does, then your question would be somewhat a duplicate of many other questions about pub/sub issues.

Comment: Damn. You are right. Forgot the subscription. Sorry for that stupid question.

Comment: It's fine, don't worry. This made me think we need a big "Why can't I see my data on the client?" question.